# Bullet item in XeLatex not appeared as expected

Tags: bullets

I used following code to add bullet but it's seems has some problem with XeLatex. It shows line (dash) instead of bullet. How can I fix this?

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{irBlogs}
\item \textit{Hamshahri}
\end{itemize}
```

result is something like below:

[image: b]

Comment: To help us help you, you should add a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050) beginning at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}` which recreates your issue. Note that there are several packages which might change the symbol used by `itemize` and that a nested `itemize` can have a different symbol from an unnested one. You can specify the used symbol (if it should be different than the rest) using the optional argument `\item[$\bullet$]` but using this for every item is tedious.

Comment: I bet that you have a nested itemize list. It is  not a bug, it is a feature, the sublist have by default this symbol. But you can change if you are not happy with the defaults. Otherwise, it has been changed already somewhere.

Comment: @Fran Thanks for your comment but it's not nested itemize list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the used symbols for `itemize` using the following:

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\cdot$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$\ast$}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textit{irBlogs}
    \item \textit{Hamshahri}
\end{itemize}   
\end{document}
```

[image]